# How to replace input text tag into plain text of it's value using C# regex?

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have html string like

```
<td AutoTab="true" Compulsory="true" ValidationGroup="OU20141008-0001" class="bn_TextBox bn_TextBox_com i" class="r">
                <span id="FixedGrid1__txtSUPPLY_AMT_0_Container">
                <input AutoTab="true" Compulsory="true" ValidationGroup="OU20141008-0001" class="bn_TextBox bn_TextBox_com r ime-disabled" name="FixedGrid1$ctl11$_txtSUPPLY_AMT" type="text" value="900000" readonly="readonly" id="FixedGrid1__txtSUPPLY_AMT_0" style="color:0;background-color:0;width:96%;" />

                </span>
            </td><td class="r">
                <span id="FixedGrid1__txtM_AMT_0_Container"><input AutoTab="true" class="bn_TextBox r ime-disabled" name="FixedGrid1$ctl11$_txtM_AMT" type="text" value="818181" readonly="readonly" id="FixedGrid1__txtM_AMT_0" style="color:0;background-color:0;width:96%;" /></span>
            </td><td class="r">
                <span id="FixedGrid1__txtTAX_AMT_0_Container"><input AutoTab="true" Compulsory="true" ValidationGroup="OU20141008-0001" class="bn_TextBox bn_TextBox_com r ime-disabled" name="FixedGrid1$ctl11$_txtTAX_AMT" type="text" value="81818" readonly="readonly" id="FixedGrid1__txtTAX_AMT_0" style="color:0;background-color:0;width:96%;" /></span>
            </td><td class="c">2014-10-08</td><td>1111</td><td class="c">
                <span id="FixedGrid1_Label5_0_Container"><span id="FixedGrid1_Label5_0" class="bn_Label">2014-10-08</span></span>

            </td><td class="c">
                <span id="FixedGrid1_Label6_0_Container"><span id="FixedGrid1_Label6_0" class="bn_Label">2014-10-08</span></span>

            </td>
```

And I need to replace this input type=text html tag into plain text of it's value.

Like

```
<input AutoTab="true" Compulsory="true" ValidationGroup="OU20141008-0001" class="bn_TextBox bn_TextBox_com r ime-disabled" name="FixedGrid1$ctl11$_txtSUPPLY_AMT" type="text" value="900000" readonly="readonly" id="FixedGrid1__txtSUPPLY_AMT_0" style="color:0;background-color:0;width:96%;" />
```

this only remains with 900000

I know there is HTML Agility pack, and it's easy and quick.

But in this case, I cannot use any of 3rd party library.

Could anyone give some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the whole input, by name is best as this should be unique tag, but capture the value attribute to use in the replacement. This is a bit simpler if you use [ExplicitCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Explicit) so you can use the name of the capture in the replacement - see [Substituting a Named Group on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx#Named)

To summarise the regex:

1. `\<input` - match the start of the tag
2. `.*?` - match the minimum characters possible to get to the next bit (the name attribute)
3. `name=""FixedGrid1\$ctl11\$_txtSUPPLY_AMT""` - match the name tag
4. `.*?` - match the minimum characters possible to get to the next bit (the value attribute)
5. `value=""(?<val>[^""]*)""` - match the value attribute and capture its value in `val`
6. `.*?` - match the minimum characters possible to get to the next bit (the end of the tag)
7. `\>` - match the end of the tag

`Regex.Replace(input, @"\<input.*?name=""FixedGrid1\$ctl11\$_txtSUPPLY_AMT"".*?value=""(?<val>[^""]*)"".*?\>", "${val}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed your code into Regex.Replace(html, @"\<input.*?value=""(?<val>[^""]*)"".*?\>", "${val}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture). Coz, I have to find all the input text tags.

Comment: Good, that should also get round the `name` and `value` attributes being the other way round. as long as there aren't any random `>`s within the tag you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do it (at least for the given example):

```
<input.+(type="text"|value="(?<Val>[^"]+)").*/>
```

The logic behind it is the following:

1. Match all `input` tags
2. Having the attributes `type=text` and `value=<something>` regardless of the order they appear
3. Capture the string in the `value` attribute in a named group `Val`
4. Match the rest of the `input` tag.

Now, to replace just use the following snippet:

```
string value = @"${Val}";
return myRegex.Replace(targetString, value);
```